# How to focus Firefox window when specific domain is visited

Tags: firefox

I use a website where my Firefox browser automatically visits websites. And I would like whenever a specific website/domain is visited for the Firefox window to come into focus on the screen.

Firefox is in the background, but not minimized.

I use Firefox version 55.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It must be an issue on your Firefox if I understand your question correctly. Have you tried to update your Firefox?

Comment: There is no issue on the Firefox. Firefox is working fine. I just want the Firefox window that is in the background visiting websites to come into focus when it visits a specific website. There is no issue with Firefox or update necessary.